# Multi-Tier Select all Checkbox System

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to create a multi layered select all feature. The aim is to be able to select all staff within a department or select all staff completely. I also need to be able to deselect.

The code I have so far is as follows: (the department select works perfectly, however I can't get the master check-all box to work)

```
<-- JAVASCRIPT --

$(function () {
$('.checkall').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
});

-- separate script --

$(function () {
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    if ($("#checkAll").is(':checked')) {
        $(".mast").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".mast").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
});

--HTML--

<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"><br/>

                                                       <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="mast"> IT Dept</div><br>
                                                             <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
                                            </fieldset>             
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                            <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="mast"> Marketing</div><br>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 5</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 6</div>
                                            </fieldset>             
                                        class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                            <fieldset><div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" name="mast"> Finance</div><br>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 1</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 2</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 3</div>
                                                        <div><input type="checkbox"> number 4</div>
                                            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some minor modification to you js, please check

```
$(function () {
  $('#checkAll').on('click', function () {
    $(document).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
$(function () {
  $(".checkall").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkMU9/) for working example

Comment: Thank you very much Sandeep :)

You sir are a good man. Works perfectly!